# Manualy trigger jenkins to clone from a git repo

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am new to Jenkins.I was wondering if there is a way to manually trigger Jenkins to clone from a git repo to my local directory .

My requirement is to have a trigger system that will clone the code to my local so that I can run a ant script on that because the ant script requires some local params

Comment: But why do you need Jenkins just to clone a repo to your local system?

Answer (score 2):

There is a git plugin helps you to clone a git repository to local directory.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

And you can write a simple script under that to do what you do periodically.